# Overflowing a list to a new line

Tags: html, css, overflow

I have a div that contains a ul list of tags as well as a combo box with a prompt to add a new tag. I am facing an issue where the list items are [exceeding the bounds of their container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Sa2I.png)

I tried adding this to the CSS,

```css
.r6o-widget.r6o-tag{
  overflow: scroll
}
```

but all that did was make the list scrollable horizontally whereas I need to be scrollable vertically (I also tried replacing `overflow` with `overflow-y` but it was still horizontal)
How can I make the list scrollable vertically or better yet, expand the container vertical and overflow its contents to a new line (I've tried `flex-wrap: wrap;` but that just overflowed the prompt rather than the list items)?

Comment: You need to add [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Believe me, these things need to be done without scrolling, since there are not so many of them. Your solution is "float" or "flex".

Comment: @UModeL yes I would prefer if the container just expanded vertically and the list items overflowed there, I'll work on an example

Comment: Use grid, flexbox or float

Comment: Using float worked, thanks

Answer (score 0):

```css
.r6o-widget.r6o-tag ul.r6o-taglist li {
  float: left !important;
}
```

this fixes the issue